# doing a mysql_query with while loop inside foreachloop in php

Tags: php, mysql, xml, foreach, while-loop

Hi am trying to go through a list of xml results and I am taking the id from these results and performing a query in my database to get more information. I have placed this into a foreach loop and then I have my while loop getting the mysql results. Everything works until I do the while loop. My page goes blank and I get no errors.. ANY help would be so appreciated!
Here is my code:

```
foreach($data->HotelList->HotelSummary as $info):
    $hotelId = $info->hotelId;
    $title=$info->name;

?>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!-----------------Listed hotel results div----------------------------->
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="listResults">

    <div class="hotelListing">
    <div class="hotelThumb">
    <?php 
    //----------Getting thumb url from database by HotelId-------
    $getImages = mysql_query("SELECT Caption FROM HotelImages WHERE ID = '4110'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($r=$mysql_fetch_array($getImages)):
        $img = $r['Caption'];
    ?>
    <img src="" width="200" height="180" alt="test image" class="thumb" />
    <?php endwhile; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Just as a note, I have tried to get num_rows and I do get the correct result. SO the query is executing, but something is happening in the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you put a `$` in front of a method call (`$mysql_fetch_array()`). It should just be `mysql_fetch_array()`.

An important issue that you shouldn't overlook is that you have a static query being called within a loop. Perform the query *outside* of your loop, since the results will never change. You can then store the results in an array and iterate through the array within your loop. This will significantly improve your code's performance.

```
<?php
//----------Getting thumb url from database by HotelId-------
$getImages = mysql_query("SELECT Caption FROM HotelImages WHERE ID = '4110'") or die(mysql_error());

$images = array();
while($img = mysql_fetch_array($getImages)) {
    $images[] = $img['Caption'];
}

foreach($data->HotelList->HotelSummary as $info):
    $hotelId = $info->hotelId;
    $title=$info->name;

?>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!-----------------Listed hotel results div----------------------------->
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="listResults">

    <div class="hotelListing">
    <div class="hotelThumb">
    <?php 

    foreach($images as $img) :
    ?>
    <img src="" width="200" height="180" alt="test image" class="thumb" />
    <?php endforeach; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I am an idiot... this is such an obvious mistake. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: No worries. Out of curiosity, where do you use `img`? I don't see it called in your code anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Your while loop is bad.  Take out the `$` in front of the function.

```
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($getImages)):
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while($r=$mysql_fetch_array($getImages)):
    $img = $r['Caption'];
?>
```

You have a `$` before the `mysql_fetch_array()`, removing that should fixed your problem.